# What kind of test cases that would crash my java program even that jvm compiled?

Tags: java, oop

[image]

This is my assignment description

https://github.com/Tony363/FCC_JAVA/blob/master/IIT/OOP/CourseGrade.java
''' java
package IIT.OOP;

```
public class CourseGrade {
    private String courseName;
    private char letterGrade;
    private static final String INV = "INVALID VALUE";
    CourseGrade(){
        this.courseName = "TBD";
        this.letterGrade = 'B';
    }
    CourseGrade(String course,char letter){
        if (this.isValidCourse(course) && this.isValidGrade(letter)){
            String temp = course;char tempG = letter;
            this.courseName = temp;this.letterGrade = tempG;
        }else {
            this.courseName = "TBD";
            this.letterGrade = 'B';
            System.out.println(INV);
        }
    }
    Boolean isValidCourse(String str){
        return str.trim().equals(str);
    }
    Boolean isValidGrade(char grade){
        return  (isAlphaNumeric(grade));
    }
    public String getCourseName(){
        String course = this.courseName;
        return course;
    }
    public char getLetterGrade(){
        char grade = this.letterGrade;
        return grade;
    }
    public void setCourseName(String course){
        if (this.isValidCourse(course)){
            String temp = course;
            this.courseName = temp;
        }else{
            System.out.println(INV);
        }
    }
    public void setLetterGrade(char grade){
        if (this.isValidGrade(grade)){
            char temp = grade;
            this.letterGrade = temp;
        }else {
            System.out.println(INV);
        }
    }
    @Override // check method signature, make sure signature already defined
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s: %c",this.getCourseName(),this.getLetterGrade());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if (o instanceof CourseGrade){
            CourseGrade d = (CourseGrade)o;
            return (this.getLetterGrade() == d.getLetterGrade()
            && this.getCourseName().equals(d.getCourseName())); 
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static boolean isAlphaNumeric(char char1) {
        return (char1 >= 'A' && char1 <= 'D') || (char1 == 'F');
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CourseGrade g = new CourseGrade("\twtf\t",'A');
        System.out.println("="+g.getCourseName()+"=");
        System.out.println("="+g.getLetterGrade()+"=");
        System.out.println("="+g+"=");
        g.setLetterGrade('A');
        g.setLetterGrade('B');
        g.setLetterGrade('C');
        g.setLetterGrade('D');
        g.setLetterGrade('F');
        // g.setLetterGrade('G');
    }
}'''
```

this is my code that "works on my computer"

[image]

This is the test case available to me that i passed, where in i still have some hidden test cases that i apparently failed to pass because my code crashed the test case.

what might be some test cases that i have not considered that would crash my program and ran with my assignents test cases?

Comment: Did you try making the constructors public? Also, even if the task doesnt state so, did you try implementing hashCode() ? Whenever you implement equals, you should always implement hashCode() accordingly. Maybe this was said somewhere in the class and theyre trying to see if you remember

Comment: I havn't tried making the constructors public. What do you mean by that i should implement hashCode() accordingly?

Comment: Theres a contract between equals and hashCode. If `a.equals(b)` then this should also be true `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`.
That means: Whenever two objects are equal, their hashCode *must* be equal too. Whenever two objects are not equal, their hashCode *may* be equal but should be avoided at best

Comment: ((String)str).trim().hashCode() == ((String)str).hashCode() like such?

Answer (score 0):

-1 as this is an assignment!! Please learn with honor, try discussing with friends or even the instructor for details.

Here we can point out lot of mistake which will go over your head as you are a beginner!!.

few to point out:

1. No arg constructor can be deleted, while maintaing the constraint.
2. validation methods should be static (try to find reason?)
3. Your issue is the famous "NULL" which is causing NullPointerExceptions.

Refer this author's book for leaning java. [Java 6 by kathy sierra](https://www.amazon.in/Programmer-Practice-Exams-310-065-Certification-ebook/dp/B004C44KIS/ref=sr_1_12?dchild=1&qid=1618588904&refinements=p_27%3AKathy%20Sierra&s=books&sr=1-12)

Comment: To 1.: The task specifically asks for a no-arg constructor

Comment: Java by default generate no arg constructor. And task hasn't asked you to assign a value in constructor only.

Comment: While this is true, the default no-arg constructor is only generated when there's no other constructor. As soon as you define an constructor with parameters, java won't generate a default no-org constructor!

Comment: my professor says its good convention in class.  i already asked my professor about possible hidden test cases, he just told me my program is throwing weird behavior that i making the tests abort. i agree with the NullPointerExceptions, i just don't know under what circumstances and what edge cases that would prompt the NullPointerException erros

Comment: @TonyFoolsOrbis both of your `isValid???` methods should check for null

Comment: null String or null is a valid input in this assignment.

Comment: @codeflush.dev agreed, guess i need some brushup. here is a nullpointer test case       CourseGrade g = new CourseGrade(null,'A');

Comment: If `null` is valid, you have to update your `isValidCourse` to return true if the course is null before calling `trim()` and you have to update your `equals` method to handle nulls correctly